# Why do I need to typecast all of the values here?

Tags: c

I'm writing a very basic program in C (new to C so just getting the hang of things) and I am struggling with TypeCasting.

It's a simple calculation program which allows you to enter two numbers and decide what you want to do with them (add, subtract, divide and multiply). Obviously, not all numbers are divisible by all other numbers and so in my switch statement for the division part I am trying to typecast the int to a float.

As requested, my variable declarations are here:

```
    int inputOne, inputTwo, calculatedValue = 0;
char calcType;
char restart = 'n';
```

I've got it to work by making all of the values typecasted, but here is what I was trying before:

```
        case 'd': case 'D':
        calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
        printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", (float)calculatedValue);
        printf("\nPlease note: This is only accurate to two decimal places.");
        break;
```

This only returns 4 without any decimal places. I then thought maybe it is due to the fact the calculation is still in int, so I changed it to this:

```
        case 'd': case 'D':
        (float)calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
        printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", (float)calculatedValue);
        printf("\nPlease note: This is only accurate to two decimal places.");
        break;
```

But this only returns 1082130432.00. No idea where that number comes from.

I got around it by using this:

```
        case 'd': case 'D':
        printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", (float)calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / (float)inputTwo);
        printf("\nPlease note: This is only accurate to two decimal places.");
        break;
```

Because it is in a switch statement, I could have got around just by using a float instead of the original integer, but I have done this code to try and understand typecasting a bit better and was under the impression it would work without having to typecast everything. Could anyone shine some light? My lecturer used the typecast in the printf and it worked fine. In his example he is trying to find the average age of students and he done so like this:

```
printf("\nAverage age: %1.2f", (cAge1 + cAge2 + cAge3) / (float)cNumStudents);
```

Hopefully that makes sense and sorry for it being so long for a simple question, I'm just trying to understand why I had to typecast everything (as my lecturer said you only need to do it to one value).

Cheers

Edit:

I just tried the following but it returns 0.00, rather than the answer.

```
calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / inputTwo;
        printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", calculatedValue);
        printf("\nPlease note: This is only accurate to two decimal places.");
        break;
```

Comment: Not the answer, but note that `(float)something = something` is [not valid in the standard C](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e99279b49f399697).

Comment: The declarations of your variables are  missing. Please show a [MCVE]. Are you sure `inputOne` and `inputTwo` contain the values you expect in first place?

Comment: The answer entirely depends on how `inputOne` and `inputTwo` are declared.  Are they `int`, or `double`, or what?

Comment: As a general rule (and especially if you're not sure what you're doing), you should avoid most typecasts, because they're usually not the right solution to a problem, and they can often make things worse, or hide real problems.  However (and as an exception to that general rule), if you have two `int` variables, and you want to divide them to produce a floating-point result, you will definitely need to cast at least one of them to `(double)` (or maybe `(float)`).

Comment: If `calculatedValue` is an int, you can *not* print it using `%1.2f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int inputOne, inputTwo;
calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / inputTwo;
```

The cast is not *needed* - there are alternatives, yet it is *used* to insure the division is computed with floating-point math rather than integer math.

Yet this is only the one step that needs review: what is the type of `calculatedValue`?  If that is also an `int`, the `float` quotient is then converted back to an `int`. and then the FP division was not of use.

```
int calculatedValue  = (float)inputOne / inputTwo; // poor code
```

Instead use a floating point (FP) type

```
float calculatedValue  = (float)inputOne / inputTwo; // better
```

---

Since `calculatedValue`, as a `float`, is converted to a `double` for printing, consider using `double` math for all typical FP operations and reserve `float` for select uses of space/speed.

```
double calculatedValue  = (double)inputOne / inputTwo; // better yet
printf("%.2f", calculatedValue);
```

---

In general, avoid casting.  It tends to hide problems.  Alternatives:

```
double calculatedValue  = 1.0 * inputOne / inputTwo;
// or 
double calculatedValue  = inputOne;
calculatedValue /= inputTwo;
```

---

Note the `1` in `%1.2f"` serves no purpose.  `1` is the specified minimum width of the printed number and a number always prints out with at least 1 character.   `%1.2f"` will always print out with at least 4 characters due to the `".2"` part. 
 Consider `%.2f"`.

Comment: Perfect, great answer thank you. calvulatedValue, inputOne and inputTwo are all declared as an int. Could you explain why the following DOES work? Is it because it is typecasting the int to a float and also the operands? printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", (float)calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / (float)inputTwo);

Comment: @MitchellWelch The `(float)calculatedValue` in `(float)calculatedValue = ...` is not valid C code.  Perhaps you are using some C compiler with a language extension or maybe another language (C++? IDK)

Comment: @MitchellWelch Please note that when we get to the end of the answer, chux is assuming that `caluclatedValue` is a `float` or a `double`.  This solution will *not* work if `calculatedValue` is an `int`.

Comment: @SteveSummit No blind assumption made.  This answer discuses the effects of both an integer and FP `caluclatedValue`.

Comment: My compiler is Visual Studio Basic with the C++ thing installed but we are renaming files to .c instead of .cpp. Maybe that's my confusion?

Comment: Hmmm, I do not think so.  After testing `(float)calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / (float)inputTwo);` is also a problem.  Transcription error?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the division itself.

Dividing two `int`s produces another `int`.  Since it's an `int`, it cannot possible have a decimal.

Casting that `int` to `float` cannot magically reintroduce the decimal that it never had.

You need to cast either of the operands to `float` so that the division itself doesn't produce an `int`.  You don't need any other casts.

Comment: They also need to make sure that `calculatedValue` is actually declared as a float or a double.

Comment: Hi. I just added the changed code to the original post but it doesn't work. Is this because the calculatedValue is set to an int anyway? Just trying to understand how to use typecasting correctly in this situation.

Comment: @MitchellWelch if `calculatedValue` is declared as an `int`, there's no way you're ever going to get a floating-point result.  You really need to show us how your variables are declared; it makes all the difference.

Comment: @SteveSummit I disagree. Check my fourth code snippet in the original post. I've also added the variables at the top.

Comment: @MitchellWelch You can disagree all you want, but you're using code that you don't understand, and that nobody else here can explain, either.  If you're disagreeing with the people who are trying to explain code that we *can* understand, then I'm not sure what we're here for.  I say again, if you are doing a division and assigning the result to `int calculatedValue`, you are never going to get a floating-point result in C.  If you're interested in getting a floating-point result in C, I can show you how, but it's going to involve a different declaration for `calculatedResult`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if you're writing a calculator for integer values, or floating-point values.

If you're writing a calculator for integer values, you don't need any casts.  When you write

```
calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
```

you will get an integer result with the remainder discarded, but that's the appropriate result for an integer-only calculator.

If you want a calculator for floating-point values, your best bet will to be declare `inputOne`, `inputTwo`, and `calculatedResult` all as `double`.  In that case, you still won't need any casts, because now, when you write

```
calculatedValue  = inputOne / inputTwo;
```

you will get floating-point division and a floating-point result.

As others have explained, if for whatever reason you have `inputOne` and `inputTwo` as integers, but you want a floating-point result, you will have to declare `calculatedResult` as `double`, and write

```
calculatedResult = (doiuble)inputOne / inputTwo;
```

You've also asked about the line

```
printf("%s%d%s%d%s%1.2f", "The value of ", inputOne, " divided by ", inputTwo, " is equal to ", (float)calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / (float)inputTwo);
```

and claimed that it works somehow.  But this is not C, so we can't explain it.  (What compiler are you using?)  In C, the expression

```
(float)calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / (float)inputTwo
```

is illegal, because the left-hand side

```
(float)calculatedValue
```

is an rvalue, and is not assignable.

Comment: Ah, that may be the case (sorry for the confusion if I'm using the wrong compiler, literally using the one the university have told me to use). My compiler is Visual Studio Basic with the C++ thing installed but we are renaming files to .c instead of .cpp. Maybe that's my confusion?

Comment: I've just noticed you said it was an rvalue, which means that it is not assignable... however it is assignable, because I can assign a value to it. If I change its declaration to float rather than int, then this would assignable without the typecast.

Comment: @MitchellWelch I am telling you it is not assignable **in C**.  Saying it is assignable because you can assign to it is like saying you can steal money from a gas station because you tried it once and got away with it. Your compiler has extensions (they all do), meaning it is compiling Visual Studio sorta-C, not standard, portable C.  If you want to fix your problem in C, we can help you.  If you want to keep using `(float)calculatedValue = something`, or understand how that works, we can't.

Answer (score 0):

The problematic part of your program boils down to this:

```
int inputOne = 10, inputTwo = 3, calculatedValue;
calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
```

`calculatedValue` is an `int`, and therefore it cannot have a fractional part. So here `calculatedValue` contains `3` after the division.

Now if you print it with `printf("%f", (float)calculatedValue)` you will get an output of `3.000000`, because the `(float)` cast will simply convert the integer value in `calculatedValue` (=3) to a `float` (=3.0).

In oder to get the expected result you might want to do this:

```
int inputOne = 10, inputTwo = 3;
float calculatedValue;
calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
```

But again `calculatedValue` will contain `3.0` and not the expected `3.33333`.
Now here the problem is that the expression `inputOne / inputTwo` is an `int` whose value is `3` (remember, both `inputOne` and `inputTwo` are `int`s), so basically you still assign the `int`!  value `3` to the `float` variable `calculatedValue`.

In order to get the expected result you can do this:

```
float inputOne = 10, float = 3;
float calculatedValue;
calculatedValue = inputOne / inputTwo;
```

All variables being of type `float`, the expresion `inputOne / inputTwo` will be a `float` and `calculatedValue` will eventually contain 3.33333.

```
int inputOne = 10, float = 3;
float calculatedValue;
calculatedValue = (float)inputOne / inputTwo;
```

Here the expression `(float)inputOne / inputTwo` is of type float (we divide a `float` by an `int`) and again yo'ill get the expected result.